# Weak convergence in Bochner space and corresponding $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm considering a sequence of functions $\{u_k\}$ which is defined on $\Omega\times(0,T)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary.
Assume we now have a uniform bound that is
$$\sup_{t\in(0,T)}\{\lVert u_k(t)\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\}\leq M$$
where $M$ is a positive constant which does not depend on $k$ and $T$.
Then I think this means that for any time $t\in(0,T)$
$$\lVert u_k(t)\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\leq M,$$
so by reflexivity of $L^2$ space, for each time, we can find a weak limit (up to a subsequence but not relabel) say $u(t)$ i.e.
$$u_k(t)\rightharpoonup u(t)\mbox{ in }L^2(\Omega)\mbox{ for every }t\in(0,T).$$
Then I also think our uniform bound on $u_k$ implies that
$$\int_{0}^{T}\lVert u_k(t)\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2dt\leq MT$$
which gives me a uniform bound in $L^2((0,T);L^2(\Omega))$. Then again by the reflexivity, we can have weak convergent subsequence, but still not relabel and name this weak limit $u^\prime$.
Hence we have that $$u_k\rightharpoonup u\mbox{ in }L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)).$$
Now I want to claim $u=u^\prime$ up to a set of zero measure in $\Omega\times(0,T)$.
Does my thought make sense or there is something wrong? Thank you for any reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example let $\Omega=(0,1)$ and
$u_{2k}(t,\omega)\equiv 1,\ u_{2k+1}(t,\omega)\equiv 0.$ Then for $0< t\le T/2 $ we choose the subsequence $u_{2k}$ which tends to $1.$ For $T/2<t<T$ we choose the subsequence $u_{2k+1}$ which tends to $0.$ Hence $$u(t,\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 & 0< t\le T/2\\
0 & T/2<t< T
\end{cases}
$$
In the space $L^2((0,T)\times \Omega)$ we choose the subsequence $u_{2k},$ hence $u'(t,\omega)\equiv 1.$ Thus $u\neq u'.$

**Remark** The main obstacle is that in the first approach the choice of the subsequence depends on every single $t\in (0,T).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now, I now where the problem is. But I have a little extra question that would taking subsequence of subsequence help? I mean for example at time $t_0$ we have a weak convergent subsequence. Then at another time $t_1$, I take weak convergent subsequence from the previous index which is weak convergent at $t_0$. Would this make a difference?

Comment: In the simple example I have provided it will work. But in general it will not, as the set of parameters $(0,T)$ is uncountable. I think the sequence $u_k(t,\omega)=\sin(kt)$ may lead to a counterexample.